# Making empty lists by typing on textfield?

Tags: dart

I created a dynamic form like this screen: [Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlvsV.png)
Is it possible to create `List` which text in textfield is the name of that list?
For example, when user types 'ab' then *Next*, a `List <dynamic> ab` is created?

Answer (score 1):

No, Dart doesn't have dynamic variable names. But you may be looking for a `Map<String, List<dynamic>>`. It would look like this :

```
var lists = {
    "ab": [],
    "ac": [],
};

lists["ad"] = ["hi"];
print(lists["ad"][0]);
```